# Grails Domain Class : hasOne, hasMany without belongsTo

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, domain-data-modelling

I am new to Grails.
Can I use "hasOne" or "hasMany" without using "belongsTo" to another domain-class?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found this article to be perfect in explaining the different cases, and includes diagrams on what effect each has on the database: http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/grails-domain-class-associations/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can. See examples in Grails doc: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.8/guide/GORM.html#manyToOneAndOneToOne

**hasMany (without belongsTo) example from the doc:**

> A one-to-many relationship is when one class, example Author, has many
>   instances of another class, example Book. With Grails you define such
>   a relationship with the hasMany setting:

```
class Author {
    static hasMany = [books: Book]
    String name
}

class Book {
    String title
}
```

> In this case we have a unidirectional one-to-many. Grails will, by
>   default, map this kind of relationship with a join table.

**hasOne (without belongsTo) example from the doc:**

> Example C

```
class Face {
    static hasOne = [nose:Nose]
}
class Nose {
    Face face
}
```

> Note that using this property puts the foreign key on the inverse
>   table to the previous example, so in this case the foreign key column
>   is stored in the nose table inside a column called face_id. Also,
>   hasOne only works with bidirectional relationships.
>
> Finally, it's a good idea to add a unique constraint on one side of
>   the one-to-one relationship:

```
class Face {
    static hasOne = [nose:Nose]
    static constraints = {
        nose unique: true
    }
}

class Nose {
    Face face
}
```

Comment: Thank you. heikkim.
It helps a lot to clear the concept!
This is feasible and link is authentic!

Comment: The documentation link is broken. => https://grails.github.io/grails2-doc/2.3.8/guide/single.html#manyToOneAndOneToOne
or for the latest doc: https://gorm.grails.org/latest/hibernate/manual/#gormAssociation

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can, but it  behave differently

```
 class Author {
        static hasMany = [books: Book]
        String name
    }

    class Book {
        String title

    }
```

In this case if you delete Author the books still existing and are independent.

```
 class Author {
        static hasMany = [books: Book]
        String name
    }

 class Book {
        String title
      static belongsTo = [author: Author]
    }
```

In this other case if you delete the Author it will delete all the books pf that author in cascade.

Many-to-one/one-to-one: saves and deletes cascade from the owner to the dependant (the class with the belongsTo).

One-to-many: saves always cascade from the one side to the many side, but if the many side has belongsTo, then deletes also cascade in that direction.

Many-to-many: only saves cascade from the "owner" to the "dependant", not deletes.

http://grails.org/doc/2.3.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/belongsTo.html

Answer (score 2):

## yes very easy like a class defintion but only specify hasMany but no need for hasOne

```
class Student {

String name

User userProfile

static hasMany =[files:File]
}


class User {

String uname

Student student

} 


class File {

String path 

Student student  // specify the belongs to like this no belong to 


}
```

Done!!