# Grails/GORM: How do Domains and Associations map to a MySql Database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, grails-orm

I'm working with GORM via Grails 3 and was wondering how domains and their associations look like when output to a MySql database.

I'm really looking for sort of a "cheat sheet" guide. Something that, for example, states:

```
String                 --> this column data type 

tablePerHierarchy true --> these tables 

hasMany                --> this table/join table 

hasMany & belongsTo    --> ...
```

I thought this would be a quick Google job, but I haven't turned up anything so far. I also understand that this is based on Hibernate so I've tried searching there as well. I may just render out these tables and note this down myself here, but before I do that does anyone in the community know if such a resource already exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best of all, just look in your database, it will be easier to see live, use **DBMS**  for this (for example [HeidiSQL](http://www.heidisql.com/), [Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) e.t.c.)

This is some examples of default data types ->

1.) **Simple data types**:

```
String     -> VARCHAR(255)
Integer    -> BIGINT
BigDecimal -> DOUBLE
Boolean    -> BIT
Date       -> DATETIME
```

2.) **Storage of domains relationships** *(To store  relations beetwen domains in database gorm adds **id** (BIGINT) and  **foreign keys**)

a.)  **hasMany :**

```
  class People { 
      ...
     hasMany = [men : Man]
  }
```

As there many men in people that is why we store **reference key** in Man domain. (*This mean people table in db will be equivalent to table without hasMany relation*)

b.) **belongsTo** , **hasOne**

```
 class Man {                      
    ...                          
    Wife wife                    
    hasOne = [Hobby]             
    belongsTo = [People]         
 }

| wife_id | hoddy_id | people_id |
```

There will be **id** (BIGINT) in Man's table : "***people_id***"  with key reference to *People* table, ***hasOne*** is similar to ***belongsTo*** and store key reference to Hobby table. (*Wife* will be simmilar to hasOne = [Wife])

if there will be no `hasMany = [men : Man]` in *People* table, there will be additional table: 'man_people'(or smth like that)

```
| man_id | people_id |
```

Fore more info about table relations you can find [>> Here <<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23905638/grails-domain-class-hasone-hasmany-without-belongsto).

By the way you can change default data type in your mapping, for example :

```
  name type: 'text'
```

Name will be LongText

P.S. Mb i missed smth, but i hope this will be small "cheat sheet" guide for you.

Comment: Difference between hasOne and belongsTo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31166149/grails-hasone-vs-belongsto